# Relative file path in java

Tags: java, relative-path

I have this code:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString(), null, 
                                          new File("D:\\Cognity"));
```

But the thing is the Cognity directory is not always in D:\, it could be in C:\ etc. So my question is if there is **a way to give it a relative path so I don't have to change this code depending on the PC that uses the program?**

Comment: Your program should ask for the path as input from the user. There's no way you can cover all possible paths. Or, you can create a config file, where you/user will provide the path to the process, and then read it in your program.

Comment: Does 'Cognity' folder has relative path to this java program itself?

Comment: You can check forcing a requirement for system path to the application

Comment: Cognity is a repository, it's usual path is either C:\Cognity, D:\Cognity, E:\Cognity, etc. you get the drift - usually only the directory could be different, the rest of the path stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `System.getProperty("user.dir"));` returns the directory from which the JVM was launched you still can't guarantee whether you're in C:\ or D:\
My advice would be to pass the *Cognity* location in as a -D commandline argument and use it like this:

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString(), null, new   File(System.getProperty("cognity.dir")));`

Comment: This also doesn't work.
 System.getProperty("cognity.dir")) returns null.

Comment: Pass it in as a command-line argument. If you havent done so then it will be null when you try to look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Call `System.getProperty("user.dir");` to get your current dir, and concat the relative path to the result.

e.g.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
path += relativePath;
```

**EDIT:**

Clarification:

For example:
The program you want to run is always located two folders backwards, and then at Temp dir.

So the relative path is `..\\..\Temp\prog.exe.`

Let's say that in one computer you have your program located at `C:\Users\user\Documents\Program`, so this is the working directory.

So:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir"); //returns the working directory
String relativePath = "\\ ..\\..\\Temp"; //no matter what is the first path, this is the relative location to the current dir
path += relativePath;
//in this example, path now equals C:\Users\user\Documents\Program\..\..\Temp\prog.exe = C:\Users\user\Temp\prog.exe
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString(), null, new File(path));
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear, should relativePath be set to something or is it just String relativePath = ""; ?

And after that, should I use the command like this: 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString(), null, 
                                          new File(relativePath));

Comment: If "working directory" means the directory where the program is executed, this will not work, because this code is part of a JIRA plug-in, which works with a git repository (Cognity), so there's no guarantee that the repository will be in the working dir.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a config-File to set the absolute-path or you create that directory in a relative path to the jar-file.